# Error 255 and "couldn't find diagnostic data" when installing cpan Inline package

Tags: perl, cpan

When I try to install the Inline package with cpan via `cpan> install Inline` I get the following error at the end:

```
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz
  /opt/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz                  : make_test NO
```

Here is the complete installation log:

```
cpan[1]> install Inline
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.18)
Going to read /root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.008)
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.88)
Going to read /root/.cpan/build/
............................................................................DONE
Found 1 old build, restored the state of 1
............................................................................DONE
Going to read /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
  Database was generated on Wed, 08 Jan 2014 07:41:07 GMT
  HTTP::Date not available
..............
  New CPAN.pm version (v2.00) available.
  [Currently running version is v1.9205]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.

CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9711)

..............................................................DONE
Going to read /root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz
............................................................................DONE
Going to write /root/.cpan/Metadata
Running install for module 'Inline'
Running make for S/SI/SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk
  Has already been made
Running make test
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/C'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/C'
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/bin/perl5.10.0 "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00init...............ok
t/01usages.............couldn't find diagnostic data in /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/pods/perldiag.pod blib/lib . /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/blib/arch /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/arm-linux /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/arm-linux /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/arm-none-linux-gnueabi /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 t/01usages.t at /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/diagnostics.pm line 268, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
Compilation failed in require at t/01usages.t line 5, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/01usages.t line 5, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
t/01usages.............dubious
        Test returned status 9 (wstat 2304, 0x900)
t/02config.............couldn't find diagnostic data in /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/pods/perldiag.pod blib/lib . /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/blib/arch /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/arm-linux /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/arm-linux /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/arm-none-linux-gnueabi /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 t/02config.t at /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/diagnostics.pm line 268, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
Compilation failed in require at t/02config.t line 5, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/02config.t line 5, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
t/02config.............dubious
        Test returned status 9 (wstat 2304, 0x900)
t/03errors.............couldn't find diagnostic data in /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/pods/perldiag.pod blib/lib . /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/blib/arch /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/arm-linux /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/arm-linux /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/arm-none-linux-gnueabi /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 t/03errors.t at /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/diagnostics.pm line 268, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
Compilation failed in require at t/03errors.t line 5, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/03errors.t line 5, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
t/03errors.............dubious
        Test returned status 9 (wstat 2304, 0x900)
t/04create.............couldn't find diagnostic data in /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/pods/perldiag.pod blib/lib . /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/blib/arch /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/arm-linux /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/arm-linux /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/arm-none-linux-gnueabi /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 t/04create.t at /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/diagnostics.pm line 268, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
Compilation failed in require at t/04create.t line 5, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/04create.t line 5, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
t/04create.............dubious
        Test returned status 9 (wstat 2304, 0x900)
t/05files..............couldn't find diagnostic data in /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/pods/perldiag.pod blib/lib . /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Inline-0.53-gk9HIk/blib/arch /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/arm-linux /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/arm-linux /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/arm-none-linux-gnueabi /opt/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 t/05files.t at /opt/lib/perl5/5.10.0/diagnostics.pm line 268, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
Compilation failed in require at t/05files.t line 5, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/05files.t line 5, <POD_DIAG> line 647.
t/05files..............dubious
        Test returned status 9 (wstat 2304, 0x900)
t/06rewrite_config.....ok
t/07rewrite2_config....ok
Failed Test  Stat Wstat Total Fail  List of Failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t/01usages.t    9  2304    ??   ??  ??
t/02config.t    9  2304    ??   ??  ??
t/03errors.t    9  2304    ??   ??  ??
t/04create.t    9  2304    ??   ??  ??
t/05files.t     9  2304    ??   ??  ??
Failed 5/8 test scripts. 0/5 subtests failed.
Files=8, Tests=5,  3 wallclock secs ( 2.30 cusr +  0.14 csys =  2.44 CPU)
Failed 5/8 test programs. 0/5 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz
  /opt/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53.tar.gz                  : make_test NO
```

Unfortunately I'm a newbie to cpan and perl, so I don't know how to resolve this issue. I already tried to reinstall perl but with no success.
If it is important for you I'm running this on my `QNAP NAS TS-419P+`:

```
[~] # uname -a
Linux QNAP 2.6.33.2 #1 Fri Jul 26 04:41:05 CST 2013 armv5tel unknown
```

Here is the perl version I'm using:

```
[~] # perl --version
This is perl, v5.10.0 built for arm-none-linux-gnueabi
```

Comment: For what it's worth, https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/perl.cpan.testers/Zc53D4tghho seems to be reporting the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

As [DavidO wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21065776/648265), the test fails at `use diagnostics;` You can check this by executing this line by itself (`perl -e 'use diagnostics;'`).

[`diagnostics.pm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) tries to read diagnostic messages from `perldiag.pod` (which is mentioned in the error message).
Looks like it's missing on your system.

So, you need to install the package with that file (or otherwise get it to the specified path) of the version corresponding to your Perl's. E.g. in Cygwin, it's in the `perl_pods` package which, you guessed it, is not installed by default.

Answer (score 2):

Investigating the first error first is always a good course of action.  In this case, that's the following:

> couldn't find diagnostic data in
>   (long list of paths excluded from copy/paste)
>   Compilation failed in require at t/01usages.t line 5,

Looking at the [distribution's source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53/) we find that line 5 of [t/01usages.t](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SISYPHUS/Inline-0.53/t/01usages.t) is:

```
use diagnostics;
```

The [diagnostics](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) pragma is part of [the core Perl distribution](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html).  For `diagnostics` to be missing necessary files indicates that the problem is that your installation of Perl is either broken or incomplete (which is the subset of "broken" most likely to be at cause here).  Resolve that issue first.

[brian's Guide to Solving Any Perl Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=376075): "Solve the first problem first."  In this case, in doing so, we discover the problem is unrelated to the module, and instead, related to the quality of your Perl installation.

Comment: Okay I noticed in another forum that I need to compile perl by myself to make it work (at least on a QNAP NAS). I tried to compile it but then another error raised. I read again in forums and the solutions seems to be that I will have to build the gcc compiler by myself, too. Unfortunately there are some more errors when I try to do this.

Comment: I'm sure the answer to this is "Because I can.", but why do you need Inline::C on a NAS device?  (I do enjoy that sort of project too) ...And yes, you're probably right: First you need a C compiler, then you need a full Perl installation, then you should be able to build Inline::C.

Comment: You might go to lists.perl.org and subscribe to the inline@perl.org mailing list.  I doubt anyone on that list has done this, but we'd probably be interested in progress reports. :)

Comment: +1 and note also http://www.mail-archive.com/cpan-testers-discuss@perl.org/msg01017.html

Comment: EDIT: Everytime I try to run `./configure` I got many of these errors: `
gawk: ./confDfiyXd/subs.awk:96: S["/; s/!.*/"]=OTOOL!%!_!# ""
gawk: ./confDfiyXd/subs.awk:96:                      ^ syntax error` (the ^ points to the %)

Comment: @DavidO: To answer your question, I need perl to use the [googlemusic-api](https://github.com/hechtus/squeezebox-googlemusic). I'm running a Logitech squeezebox-server on my QNAP NAS and I'd like to be able to play my music from gmusic.